# Outputs negative number after parsing ints in a 1000 digit string

Tags: java

So, the problem I'm solving is in the comments of this program. The digits I'm multiplying appear to be positive and yet I'm getting negative outputs. I tried using a byte instead of ints but that didn't solve the problem.

```
public class LargestProduct{
```

/*The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?*/

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String digit = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    String characters[] = new String[1000];
    int multipliers[] = new int[987];
    int intcharacters[] = new int[1000];
    byte test[] = new byte[1000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        characters[i] = "";
        characters[i] = characters[i] + digit.charAt(i);
        intcharacters[i] = Integer.parseInt(characters[i]);
        test[i] = (byte) intcharacters[i];
    }
    //System.out.println(intcharacters[1]);
    boolean yes = false;
    for(int i = 0; i< 987; i ++){
        for(int f= i; f<i+14; f++){

        intcharacters[i] = intcharacters[i]*intcharacters[f];
        if(intcharacters[i] < 0){
            System.out.println(intcharacters[i] + " " + intcharacters[f] + " " + f + " " + i);
            yes = true;
            break;
        }

        }
        if(yes == true){
            break;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregarding some other problems in the code, let's focus on the whole "negative number from two positives" thing:

Numbers in java are stored as either 8-bit (`char` or `byte`), 16 bit (`short`, but really, never use these) or 32-bit (`int`, use this unless you have a good reason not to).

These numbers have a fixed finite upper limit; for `int`s, it's 2^31, which is roughly equal to 4 billion. If you exceed this, the number will "overflow" to a negative number, hence the odd results. Because in computer land, the left-most (31st) bit is the "sign bit", and when you add one to a number that's already at its upper limit, you "overflow" it to its lower limit (roughly -4 billion).

Obviously your "thousand digit" number is much, much, MUCH bigger than this. So you're going to want to use a class called `BigInteger`.

It supports what's called "arbitrary precision" arithmetic, so you'll never have a problem with overflows. But be aware, it's horrendously slow compared to a regular integer since it must be represented in a much more complex way, so be wary using it.